# Magento 2.4 Backend extremly slow

Tags: backend, magento2.4, aws

i'm using Magento 2.4 under AWS ec2 instance.
The frontend is okey, but the backend is extremly slow.

Admin access is 15 seconds,
product page is around 20 seconds.

I have around 1500 products, and i don't understand why it's taking so muchtime.

Can you help me?

Comment: please check the error logs to get a hint

Comment: there is no error in logs. i only have got this list:

Comment: [2021-05-14 13:59:58] main.INFO: Add of item with id Ess_M2ePro::walmart_help_center_documentation was processed [] []
[2021-05-14 13:59:58] main.INFO: Add of item with id Ess_M2ePro::walmart_help_center_knowledge_base was processed [] []
[2021-05-14 13:59:58] main.INFO: Add of item with id Ess_M2ePro::walmart_help_center_ideas_workshop was processed [] []
[2021-05-14 13:59:58] main.INFO: Add of item with id Ess_M2ePro::walmart_help_center_community_forum was processed [] []

Comment: with lots of other module

Comment: Please check the network tab when you loading the admin, it seems lots of API calls / or http requests going to 3rd party Or kind of scheduled job is running frequently.